# Generalization of du Bois-Reymond Lemma into dimension 2?

Tags: calculus-of-variations

The du Bois-Reymond lemma reads as follows:

> Let $ f \in L^1 (a,b) $ satisfies 
>   \begin{equation*}
> \int^b_a f(t) \varphi'(t) dt =0, \ \  \forall \varphi \in C^{\infty}_0(a,b),
> \end{equation*}
>   then $ f(t) = c, \ a.e. \ t \in (a,b)$.

Now we consider to generalize it into case of dimension $ 2 $ with mixed partial derivatives:

> Assume that $ g \in L^1((a,b)\times(a,b))$ and satifies
>   \begin{equation*} 
> \int^b_a\int^b_a g \frac{\partial^2
>  \varphi}{\partial x \partial y} dxdy =0, \ \  \forall \varphi \in
> C^{\infty}_0((a,b)\times(a,b)). 
> \end{equation*} 
>   Can we claim that $ g =
> c_0 p (x) +c_1 q(y) +c_2, \ a.e. \ (x,y) \in (a,b) \times (a,b) $?

Comment: The answer is yes; see Theorem 3.1.4'  the  volume 1 of Hormander's book *The Analysis of Linear Partial Differential Operators*

Comment: @Liviu Nicolaescu Thank you for your comment. The Theorem 3.1.4' gives a result with condition $ \partial_n u = 0 (\int_{Y \times I } u \frac{\partial{\varphi}}{{\partial x_n}} = 0 ) $, i can not correspond this result to the question exactly. Can you explain how the result work for the question with more details? Expanding to an answer may be more helpful?

Comment: The equality $(\partial_x(\partial_yg)=\int u_0(x)\partial^2_{xy}\phi(x,y) dxdy=0$ holds *for any*  compactly supported  $\phi$. Take $\phi$ of the form $\alpha(x)\beta(y)$ $\alpha,\beta$ compactly supported.

Comment: @ Liviu Nicolaescu Following your instructions, we obtain $ \int^b_a dy ( \frac{\partial \beta}{\partial y} \int^b_a \frac{\partial  \alpha }{\partial x} gdx ) = 0, \forall \alpha(x), \beta(y) \in C^\infty_0(a,b) $. Using du Bois-Reymond lemma of dimension one for $ \beta $ yeilds that $ \int^b_a \frac{\partial \alpha}{\partial x} g dx = p_0 (x) + c_0, \forall \alpha \in C^\infty_0 $.  Now i have no idea how to move on.

Answer (score 1):

Your condition means that on $(a,b)^2$, you have
$
\frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial x\partial y}=0
$
in the distribution sense. As a result you have
$$
\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}=1\otimes \beta(y),\quad\text{that is a distribution "depending only on $y$",}
$$
which implies that
$
g=A(x)\otimes 1+ 1\otimes B(y),
$
where $A,B$ are distributions on $(a,b)$. Since $g$ belongs to $L^1((a,b)^2)$, this implies that both $A,B$ belong to $L^1((a,b))$.